# FQL query for links now only returns public links

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

When testing an app i was building, I noticed that after querying the links table using FQL (with a simple call to https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+url,+title+FROM+link+WHERE+owner=me()) - the query only returned public links.

I have recently (today) updated my access token by removing my app from the list of approved apps and adding  it again.

Can someone please tell me how to use FQL to access all of the links a user has shared, and not just the public ones? Where and how do I edit the permissions for my app to achieve this?

Thanks in advance